# constructor ImageLoader(Context) is undefined / constructor ImageLoader() is not visible

Tags: java, android, constructor, undefined, lazylist

I am getting the following error "constructor ImageLoader(Context) is undefined" at this line.

```
imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

If i change it to

```
imageLoader=new ImageLoader();
```

it tells me that "constructor ImageLoader() is not visible"

What am i doing wrong?

Here is the **Gallerie.java** where i call the LazyAdapter

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import com.example.androidhive.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Gallerie extends Activity {    ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallerie);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
        adapter.imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private String[] mStrings={
        "http://feuerwehr-alfter.de/images/com_reports/gallery/IMG_3036_551.jpg",
        "http://feuerwehr-alfter.de/images/com_reports/gallery/IMG_0881_550.jpg",
        "http://feuerwehr-alfter.de/images/com_reports/gallery/IMG_0894_550.jpg",

};
}
```

here is my **LazyAdapter.java** which shows the error

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.example.androidhive.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageLoader.displayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

And here the **ImageLoader.java** where the constructor for the ImageLoader is in.

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.example.androidhive.R;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler=new Handler();//handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `LazyAdapter()` constructor from this...

```
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d){}
```

to this...

```
public LazyAdapter(Context context, String[] d){}
```

Then pass the `Context` object through the `ImageLoader()` constructor as follows...

```
Context mContext;

public LazyAdapter(Context context, String[] d) {
    mContext = context;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(mContext);
}
```

Comment: No I'm getting "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type LazyAdapter" errror

Comment: With the updatet code i Keep getting still the same error like before "constructor ImageLoader(Context) is undefined"

Comment: Your application package is `com.example.androidhive;` but you are importing `R.java` file from `com.example.FFAlfter` where it should be `com.example.androidhive`. why?

Comment: For some reason in th androidmanifest was standing FFAlfter. Changed it back to androidhive and fixed it in all *.class.

The Problem is still the same. :/

Comment: clean your project and then run it.

Comment: Did the cleanup, no success